# Firebase code in Javascript does not execute in the Stripe web hook URL

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/en-nl) in a web project and in a PHP file at a web hook URL (i.e. https://something/flutter_web/index.php) of Stripe, I am trying to access the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) database
in Javascript. But that does not do anything in the firebase database i.e. no entry recorded in Firebase. But if I just run the PHP file even in my localhost server, it works i.e. records an entry in the Firebase database.

MY full code in `index.php` follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Firebase app</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<h1>FIREBASE APP</h1>

<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getFirestore,collection, addDoc, getDocs, doc, setDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"; 
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...KGG7P0",
    authDomain: "....2.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "...e-81e62",
    storageBucket: ".....appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "..115",
    appId: "....df3c8960b7a1b6"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  var product_id ='oooprod_MYeB8eh6i00qyz_ppppppppppp';
  var product_info =JSON.parse('{"id":"prod_MYeB8eh6i00qyz","object":"product","active":true,"attributes":[],"created":1664973567,"default_price":"price_1LpWsoSCaGUwBkx9pFbkbJrh","description":"description for Demo 1111","images":[],"livemode":false,"metadata":[],"name":"Demo 1111","package_dimensions":null,"shippable":null,"statement_descriptor":null,"tax_code":null,"type":"service","unit_label":null,"updated":1664973572,"url":null}');

  await setDoc(doc(db, "subscriptions", product_id), product_info);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**How to make the code execute in the web hook URL ?**

Comment: Are you sure the php page is really called by stripe? Also, with such a webhook, you should usually send back an HTTP code (e.g. 200). I would suggest you use an HTTP Cloud Function or implement a real API endpoint with your php server.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, actually I made the code snippet very simple excluding many other parts. The PHP page is called as I can see the HTML output from the WebHooks sections of Stripe developer dashboard. Yes, an HTTP code (e.g. 200) is sent but I omitted that along with  other parts (e.g. events such as `product.created`,'price.created' etc.). How can I make a real API endpoint with my php server other than using a URL as the web hook ?  Regarding the HTTP Cloud Function , i think you hint at Firebase Cloud functionc, right ? But that is not free.

Comment: Yes I was referring to a Cloud Function. And it’s usually not expensive at all, see https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-pricing and note that there is a free tier of 2M invocations per month

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, what can be the reason that the code does not execute ? I can only see the full HTML in web hook response. Can you test the code as a demo ?